# How do I convince iTunes to play a podcast item I've manually replaced

Tags: podcasts, itunes

I'm subscribed to a podcast which recently had two episodes listed with links to files which were only a few bytes big. I have no idea what went wrong on their end, but my copy of iTunes downloaded these, and I could 'play' them.

Now the songs on the server have been updated, but I cannot convince iTunes to re-fetch the files. Removing the podcast is not an option as I have 4 years of history from that podcast saved locally and I don't want to lose it.

I'm a software developer myself, so I figured, I'll just use `curl` and manually get the updated files, copy them over the originals, restart iTunes, and all will be well. Not so. iTunes is still playing less then a second of the file before stopping again. However, I can hear the start of the actual podcast now, so it's playing the new file, and it has also updated the length of the file (as displayed in the podcast's list of items in iTunes itself) to something I assume is correct, much longer than the 0 seconds it was before.

The mp3 files themselves play fine in VLC. **How can I get iTunes to normally recognize the new files?**

(if it matters, I'm on Lion with all the latest updates. iTunes version 10.5.1. I'm not syncing with any other devices.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Delete the corrupted episode
- <kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd>-click on the triangle in front of the Podcast name
- All available episodes will be displayed in addition to the ones you already downloaded, together with a button to download them individually

Comment: Great, thanks! That did the trick. Followup question: how do I figure this kind of thing out myself? I tried googling and looking at the iTunes help, both didn't prove useful to me. What magic trick did I miss? :-)

Comment: Pressing Alt/Opt on a mouse click often provides additional functionality.